# Count unique values between 2 dates

Tags: vb.net

I created a simple database  that contains dates and name values.I would like to seek some idea how to vba code to count specific value between two days.

The case is like this:
Column A: list of date
Column B:list of Name

For example:
(Col A   ,  Col B) :row1(10/01/19   , Arctic),row2(10/02/19  ,  Polar),r3(10/02/19  ,  Polar),r4(10/02/19 ,   Arctic),r5(10/02/19  ,  Arctic),r6(10/03/19,    Arctic)

Please note that the result I wish to get is:
Counr of Arctic=3
Count of Polar =1

Please note that "Polar" appears twice on 10/02/19, however, I want to count it as 1 only within the range of 10/01/19 to 10/03/19 since these two occurence of "Polar" happen in the same date. Same will be applied to "Arctic" and more names if theres any.

Please see attached image for a clearer data sample.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: VBA or VB.Net? Post some code.

Comment: Your problem statement is very clear, good work. Note, however, that VBA (as mentioned in your question) and VB.NET (as mentioned in your tags) are **completely different** programming languages. Please clarify which one you use. In addition, a problem like this can usually be solved with SQL more efficiently than with the front-end programming language, so it would also be helpful to know which database engine you use.

Comment: Pardon for not clearly stating the tag. It should be VBA. Looking forward fo a response.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.name, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table T
WHERE T.date > date1 AND T.date < date2
GROUP BY T.name
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.